# В какую папку в Laravel можно добавлять доп файлы php

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно создать 2 файла. Один с настройками БД и еще один. Где я могу хранить эти 2 файла чтобы спокойно сделать импорт в основной файл php?

Comment: почитайте документацию. Ибо на ваш вопрос очень трудно ответить. Есил в двух словах то ларавель использует composer, и про импорт файлов можете забыть. Все конфигы от базы итд. принято писать в .env файле, либо в папке config

Comment: @ВадимАлександру Спасибо. То что и нужно было узнать)